# What kind of projection is this?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, compactness, transformation, projection

> Q: What kind of projection is this?

I found the following maps by investigating a function $\phi(x)=\exp\big(\frac{1}{\log(x)}\big)$ and intersecting it with rays from the origin. The maps essentially swap the two branches of the graph of $y=\phi(x)$.

$$ (x,\phi(x)) \mapsto \big(\frac{1}{\phi(x)},\frac{1}{x}\big),~~x\in(e,\infty) $$

$$ (x,x) \mapsto \big(\frac{1}{x},\frac{1}{x}\big)~~ x=e $$

$$  (x,\phi(x)) \mapsto \big(\frac{1}{\phi(x)},\frac{1}{x}\big), ~~x\in(-\infty,e) $$

By letting rays extend from the origin and intersect $\phi(x)$ the projection from the function to itself becomes clear. Feel free to verify my claim of the above mappings. Here's a picture of the function $y=\phi(x)$ and a visual aid of what's going on:

[image]

Comment: In a log-log plot (i.e. define $u=\log x,v=\log y$) the map $(x,y)\mapsto(1/y,1/x)$ is a reflection about the line $u+v=0$.

Comment: And of course, in log-log space your function $y=\phi(x)$ becomes the hyperbola $uv=1$, whose branches are indeed swapped by the above reflection.